# SQL Match Values in One Table to Highest Values in another Table to Pull Date from Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to establish the last time an inventory item was received and only display this date along with every inventory item, but I also need to pull other information like Warehouse Names.

I am using the following tables:

- **Inventory**: Contains Inventory Counts
- **Part_Info**: Contains Part Information (Description, Warehouse Identifier)
- **Warehouse_Info**: Contains Warehouse Names
- **Received_Parts**: Contains a journal of all received parts, no date information however.
- **Receive_Master**: Contains the Date of the Received Parts by the Receiving ID.

My thought process:

- Join Inventory to Part_Info by PartID: This gives me Details, Names, Descriptions of the Part.
- Join Inventory to Warehouse_Info by WarehouseID: This gets me the warehouse name.

Then here is where I get stuck.

Received_Parts has all the parts received but does not have the date information.  To get the date information, I need to tie back to Receive_Master by the Received_Parts_ID.

I was thinking I could grab the highest receipt_parts_id for the particular PartID via the MAX() function and then tie that back to Receive_Master to pull the date for that particular entry.

Unfortunately, every join attempt I have made has failed.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
   select 
  a.*,
  b.*,
  c.*,
  d.*,
  e.*
FROM dbo.IN_Inventory a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IN_Part b
        ON a.Part_Id = b.part_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN IN_Warehouse c
        ON a.Warehouse_Id = c.Warehouse_Id
    INNER JOIN IN_Receipt_Parts d
        ON a.Part_Id = d.Part_Id
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT part_id, receipt_id, MAX(receipt_parts_id) maxReceipt
        FROM IN_Receipt_Parts
        GROUP BY Part_Id
    ) e ON d.Part_Id = e.Part_Id AND d.Receipt_Parts_Id = e.maxReceipt
    LEFT OUTER JOIN IN_Receipt f
        ON e.Receipt_Id = f.Receipt_Id
WHERE
    a.On_Hand_New > 0
```

Comment: Could you script out the table schema with some sample data? Something so I could run it on my local box to test

Comment: Is this sql server or MySql? They are not the same thing and the answer can very greatly.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and we can probably help you sort it out.

Comment: It's SQL Server, sorry about that, I thought I had it tagged correctly (I just fixed it).  Here's what I tried so far:

Comment: Okay, so no idea how to post the sql script here in the comments. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after (you'd get the date from the derived table). Replace "DateField" with the date column you're looking for. I don't think you referenced in your latest attempt.

```
             select 
  a.*,
  b.*,
  c.*,
  e.*
FROM dbo.IN_Inventory a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IN_Part b
        ON a.Part_Id = b.part_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN IN_Warehouse c
        ON a.Warehouse_Id = c.Warehouse_Id
    INNER JOIN
    (
         SELECT p.part_id, m.DateField, Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY p.Part_Id ORDER BY m.DateField DESC) RowNumber
        FROM IN_Receipt_Parts p INNER JOIN 
            IN_Receipt  m ON p.receipt_id=m.Receipt_ID 
    ) e ON e.part_id=a.Part_id and RowNumber=1
WHERE
    a.On_Hand_New > 0
```

Comment: This pulls about 20x too many rows, it looks like it is pulling a row for every qty item in the receipt.

Comment: Ahhh I see the problem I left in your reference to In_receipt_parts (aliased d). Whatever you need from that table should be added to the derived table. I've edited my answer to remove that, but you'll need to add any add'l column you need. (Since I don't know with all the *s, which ones you need.